# How to configure EXPLORER_CONNECTION_NAME using django-sql-explorer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using `django-sql-explorer` and I have three database connections in `setting.py`.

I have the following configuration in `setting.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'explorer',
    ...
)
EXPLORER_CONNECTIONS = {
    'Default': 'readonly',
}
EXPLORER_DEFAULT_CONNECTION = 'readonly'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'bazaar360',
        'HOST': 'demodb.birdeye.com',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
    'integrationdb2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'bazaar360',
        'HOST': 'demodb.birdeye.com',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
    'integrationdb3': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'bazaar360',
        'HOST': 'demodb.birdeye.com',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

And in `urls.py` I added:

```
...
url(r'^explorer/', include('explorer.urls')),
...
```

I want to run query in there, but I got an exception while running said query.
I just want to understand how can I pass `EXPLORER_CONNECTION_NAME` values.

Answer (score 4):

Use below code in setting file.

```
EXPLORER_CONNECTIONS = { 'Default': 'default' }
EXPLORER_DEFAULT_CONNECTION = 'default'
```